# Putting labels in an array using for loop in Visual Studio C#

Tags: c#, winforms, for-loop

I want to put labels in an array on form load but instead of coding them one by one, I want to use a for loop but I don't know how this works in C#.

My Code:

```
Dates[0] = this.labelrect0; 
Dates[1] = this.labelrect1;
Dates[2] = this.labelrect2;
Dates[3] = this.labelrect3;
```

What I want to do:

```
for(int n = 0; int > array.Count; c++)
{
 Dates[n] = this.labelrect+n;  //how do i concatenate n to labelrect?
}
```

Comment: A non-direct way could be to put the labels in an `Label[] labelrect` array and address them by `labelrect[n]`. Then `Dates[n] = this.labelrect[n]` in a loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if `Dates` is an `Label[]` you can try this:

```
for(int n = 0; n < array.Count; n++)
{
 Dates[n] =(Label) Controls.Find("labelrect"+n, true)[0]; 
}
```

Comment: May I ask what does the [0] at the end of the line do?

Comment: @Sai: `Control.Find()` method returns the Array of controls matching with the given name , so that we should consider the first item from the array.

Comment: I see. Oh by the way, Controls.Find asks 2 arguments so I used Controls.Find("labelrect"+n, true) because the 2nd argument is a bool which asks if I want to search for the child controls or not. Anyway I got it working. Thanks!

Comment: @Sai: yes you are right, there willbe two parameters,i updated my post. glad tobe help of you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Controls`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.controls.aspx) property. If you have a `Container` control which contains these labels, then you can get the collection of controls contained within the control with `<ContainerID>.Controls`.

Answer (score 0):

I normally will put the Index of the Label in the Tag Property then I would then iterate through the Control Collection using the Tag to assign the Control to the proper Index. Something like this.

```
for (int i = 0; i < Controls.Count; i++)
{
    if(Controls[i] is Label)
        Dates[int.Parse(Controls[i].Tag.ToString())] = (Label)Controls[i];
}
```